# Unable to POST via JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json

I am trying to send user text from a web page to my flask app to run a script on the user text and then return a result. The problem I am having is that the text isn't appearing on the server (flask_app.py) side. Here is the .js that is supposed to be sending the text (index.js):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('I have loaded');

    //Grab DOM elements to use later
    analyzeTextButton = $("#analyze-button");


    analyzeTextButton.click(function() {
        // get text
        text = $("#user-text").val();
        //console.log(text); //This part works

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "analyze",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                text
            },
             success: function(results, results2, verbs) {
             text = results.text;
             console.log("Success!");
             console.log(verbs);
             }
        })      
    })
```

Here is the Flask app that is trying to receive it. I've tried several different versions (from other Stack Overflow questions and various tutorials) but none of them work. They are labeled content1-5.

flask_app.py:

```
@app.route('/analyze', methods=['POST'])
def analyze():
    print('You made it to analyze', file=sys.stderr) #This gets printed
    content = request.get_json(silent=True)
    content2 = request.json
    content3 = request.get_json()
    content4 = request.form.get('html', '')
    content5 = request.form['contents']
    print(content, file=sys.stderr) #These all return "None"
    print(content2, file=sys.stderr) #Trying to make them return user text
    print(content3, file=sys.stderr)
    print(content4, file=sys.stderr)
    print(content5, file=sys.stderr)
    text = "The text is not being found"
    results = my_script(content) #Run a script on whichever works
    return jsonify({'results': results})
```

Here is the page that is trying to send the information (index.html):

```
  <div class="row">
<form role="form" method='POST' action='#'>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="user-text" name="contents" placeholder="Enter a comment"></textarea>
  <button type="button" id="analyze-button" class="btn btn-default">Not Working Button</button>
  <button type="submit" id="analyze-button2" class="btn btn-default">Working Button</button>
</form>
```

EDIT: When I look in my browser, I see that POST appears to be sending the correct string: "here+is+my+text"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request needed to specify that the text was html:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "analyze",
        data: {html:text},
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function (ret) {
          alert('JSON posted: ' + JSON.stringify(ret));
        }
      });
```

On the flask app the request can be read with this line:

```
content4 = request.form.get('html', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data: {
      text
}
```

should be proper JSON,it should be something like

```
data: {
      "value":text
}
```

where `value` is key and text variable is value.

Comment: I added "value" like you suggested and I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: what is the error you are getting , and is you flask app able to receice JSON data request with `value` key?

Comment: Check in the browser what the POST request is actually sending.

Comment: It appears to be sending the correct values. After the "value" change it is: value:"here+is+my+text"

Comment: then problem in on flask side, have a look at this http://code.runnable.com/UpYDdiBGFJNXAAAz/parse-json-request-data-from-request-in-flask-for-python

Comment: That appears to be what I have:  content2 = request.json

Comment: are you getting similar result in content2?

Comment: Yes, they all return the value "None"

Comment: I guess your flash application is not able to parse JSON , `contentType: 'application/json',` put this inside ajax call and try

Comment: I added contentType as you suggested. Same result

Comment: Look at index.html at http://code.runnable.com/UpYDdiBGFJNXAAAz/parse-json-request-data-from-request-in-flask-for-python its working peacefully for me.

Comment: I copied and pasted the $.ajax portion and changed the url to match mine and I'm still getting the same result. All of the content values are None

Comment: Directly hit analyse API from POSTMAN and check